# how to programmatically access the builtin properties of an open xml worddoc file

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk

i would like to access some built in properties(like author,last modified date,etc.) of an open xml word doc file. i would like to use open xml sdk2.0 for this purpose. so i wonder if there is any class or any way i could programmatically access these builtin properties.

Comment: Look at this code for some nice hints: [https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/10033886/](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/10033886/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An explanation of the following method can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb739835%28office.12%29.aspx#ManipulatingWord2007OpenXMLFiles_RetrieveaDocumentCoreProperty), but pretty much you need to pass in the properties that you want to get out of the core.xml file to this method and it will return the value:

```
public static string WDRetrieveCoreProperty(string docName, string propertyName)
{
   // Given a document name and a core property, retrieve the value of the property.
   // Note that because this code uses the SelectSingleNode method, 
   // the search is case sensitive. That is, looking for "Author" is not 
   // the same as looking for "author".

   const string corePropertiesSchema = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/metadata/core-properties";
   const string dcPropertiesSchema = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/";
   const string dcTermsPropertiesSchema = "http://purl.org/dc/terms/";

   string propertyValue = string.Empty;

   using (WordprocessingDocument wdPackage = WordprocessingDocument.Open(docName, true))
   {
      // Get the core properties part (core.xml).
      CoreFilePropertiesPart corePropertiesPart = wdPackage.CoreFilePropertiesPart;

      // Manage namespaces to perform XML XPath queries.
      NameTable nt = new NameTable();
      XmlNamespaceManager nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(nt);
      nsManager.AddNamespace("cp", corePropertiesSchema);
      nsManager.AddNamespace("dc", dcPropertiesSchema);
      nsManager.AddNamespace("dcterms", dcTermsPropertiesSchema);

      // Get the properties from the package.
      XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument(nt);

      // Load the XML in the part into an XmlDocument instance.
      xdoc.Load(corePropertiesPart.GetStream());

      string searchString = string.Format("//cp:coreProperties/{0}", propertyName);

      XmlNode xNode = xdoc.SelectSingleNode(searchString, nsManager);
      if (!(xNode == null))
      {
         propertyValue = xNode.InnerText;
      }
   }

   return propertyValue;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the packaging API:

```
using System.IO.Packaging.Package;

[...]

using (var package = Package.Open(path))
{
    package.PackageProperties.Creator = Environment.UserName;
    package.PackageProperties.LastModifiedBy = Environment.UserName;
}
```

That works also for other open XML formats like power point.

Comment: fine! i used for xlsx

Comment: Thanks! I know it's not part of the question but to save the properties changed in this example use:  package.Close();

Answer (score -1):

package.Save();
Then 
package.closed;

I think that Is the best way.